# Configuring Spring Security to Authenticate against LDAP without anonymous and without bind DN

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-ldap

Using JNDI I can successfully authenticate against our LDAP server, which has anonymous binds disabled, using only the user's username and password, like this:

```
    Hashtable<String, Object> env = new Hashtable<String, Object>();
    env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
    env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, url);

    env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, userName);
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, password);
    DirContext ctx = new InitialDirContext(env);
    Attribute groups = ctx.getAttributes(userName).get("groupMembership");
```

Now I would like to do the same thing using Spring Boot, Spring Security, and Spring LDAP.

I can successfully configure authentication using a bind DN and password, like this:

```
    DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource context = new DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource(ldapConfig.url);
    context.setUserDn(ldapConfig.bindDn);
    String bindPassword = passwordResolver.getPassword(ldapConfig.password);
    context.setPassword(bindPassword);
    context.afterPropertiesSet();

    CustomAuthoritiesPopulator customAuthoritiesPopulator = new CustomAuthoritiesPopulator(context, ldapConfig.groupSearchBase);

    String[] dnPatArr = new String[ldapConfig.userDnPatterns.size()];
    ldapConfig.userDnPatterns.toArray(dnPatArr);

    auth.ldapAuthentication()
        .ldapAuthoritiesPopulator(customAuthoritiesPopulator)
        .contextSource(context)
        .userDnPatterns(dnPatArr)
        .groupSearchBase(ldapConfig.groupSearchBase);
```

This works--the Spring Boot webapp will authenticate my users successfully.

But I would like to do this without passing in the bind DN and bind password, just like I did with the JNDI example.

If I simply omit setting the bind DN and password, I will get "LDAP: error code 48 - Anonymous Simple Bind Disabled.".

I don't want to do an anonymous bind--I want Spring to use the username and password the user provides to do a simple bind against each of my bind DN patterns until one works.

I've read the docs but I'm having a hard time determining whether or not that is possible. JNDI can do it so I figure I should be able to get Spring to do it. I've thought about writing my own custom Spring Security authentication provider but surely that's not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

In the JNDI, authentication information is specified in environment properties. Please make sure the property names are spelled correctly.

For example environment property for credentials is  `java.naming.security.credentials` not `java.naming.security.credential`. Notice the `missing letter 's'` at the end would give

> "LDAP: error code 48 - Anonymous Simple Bind Disabled."

```
<bean id="jndiTemplate" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate">      
    <property name="environment">
        <props>
            <prop key="java.naming.factory.initial">com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory</prop>
            <prop key="java.naming.provider.url">ldap://serverURL/jndi_ctx
            </prop>
            <prop key="java.naming.security.authentication">simple</prop>
            <prop key="java.naming.security.principal">user_id</prop>
            <prop key="java.naming.security.credentials">password</prop>            
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```